# Java compatibility issue with Talend

Tags: java

I installed Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 8.0.1.  Initially, I had java version 8 of JRE installed and I was getting the error message that 'version 1.8.0_321 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.  Version: 11 or greater is required'.  So I installed java version 11 of jdk and now I get the error message 'Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run TOS_DI-win-x86_64. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin'.

Comment: You need to edit your Java system environment variable or modify the configuration of Talend so it can find Java 11 (which isn’t even the current version)

Comment: Make sure the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` points to the install did of the JDK. Most programs that need a JDK use this env variable to find it.

Comment: Also it is wise to set `PATH` to point to new version.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need java for other software uninstall version 1.8. Then try to uninstall version 11. And after this install the last available version of java JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows)

Answer (score 1):

After changing the PATH and HOME and the TOS ini file, I was still getting the error.  I found that I could launch TOS directly from the directory, but get the error launching from the shortcut.  Found out the shortcut set up by the install includes the Java path in the Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\TOS_DI-8.0.1\studio\TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bat file in Talend installation folder, in my case is:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\TOS_DI-8.0.1\studio`, and indicate which Java Version to use:

`openTalend.bat`:

```
TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin"
```

To open Talend, run bat file.

Answer (score -1):

THE PROBLEM is in the shortcut of Talend, no matter what you have done the shortcut has a field named 'Target' which has a value something like this in my case

> "D:\Program Files (x86)\TOS_DI-8.0.1\studio\TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe" **-vm** "C:\Program Files\ **Java\jdk-11**\bin"

As you can see it's a command settled the first time you installed Talend so if you need to change the version of JDK, change this path here also for the new JDK.

Note: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Double click</kbd> to see the shortcut parameters.